# TreeView не работает скрол при DragAndDrop

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

Использую `TreeView` для проекта, со вложенными элементами. Перемещение элементов осуществляется через DragAndDrop. Когда начинаю перемещать элемент, то скрол не работает, а необходимо переместить в каталог выше в списке. Как решить задачу?

```cs
<TreeView 
    x:Name="TreeViewShareFolders" 
    Height="700" 
    VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,10,0,0">

    <TreeView.ItemTemplate >

        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Nodes}">

            <StackPanel 
                Orientation="Horizontal"   
                AllowDrop="True"
                MouseLeftButtonDown="TreeViewShareFolders_MouseLeftButtonDown" 
                Background="{x:Null}"
                Drop="StackPanel_Drop">

                <TextBlock  
                    Text="{Binding Name}" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"  />

                <Rectangle 
                    Fill="{Binding Color}" 
                    Width="6" 
                    Height="6" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                    RadiusX="5" 
                    RadiusY="5" 
                    Margin="10,3,0,0"/>
            </StackPanel>

        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>

</TreeView>
```

Comment: Это? https://stackoverflow.com/a/1316377/276994

Comment: @VladD не подходит для меня.

Comment: А можно немного деталей? Почему не подходит?

Comment: @VladD У меня нет ScrollViewer. Если я правильно сделал, то устанавливаю
ListBox li = sender as ListBox; => TreeView tv = sender as TreeView;
ScrollViewer sv = FindVisualChild<ScrollViewer>(ItemsList); `itemList` - это что должно быть? Нужно добавить ScrollViewer, если да, то куда? У меня сейчас их два появляется.